# Painted Shapes are Flashy and Jumpy when Repainting?

Tags: java, graphics, applet, paint

I made an Applet that paints shapes in the Windows, then each frame, I make them go down to simulate Basic Gravity but the shape flashes alot ( Which is unwanted ) And I couldn't find a way to make it Smooth. I don't mind slight lag for Smooth Graphics.

Comment: Without you posting your basic architecture - i.e. Frame + paint implementation - it is impossible to give you an insightful answer other than to investigate double buffering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you're about to discover double buffering:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_buffering#Double_buffering_in_computer_graphics

For help implementing it in Java:
http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/doublebuf.html

Comment: Required a bit more Googling on the subject, but that was exactly what I needed, thanks!

Comment: Are you *this* [Ryan Stewart](http://pscode.org/j2ee/tomcat.html)?  Your (v. instructive - loved the Salsa recipe!) blog makes me think so.

Comment: Holy crap. Who are you, and where did that thing come from?? I wrote that years ago as an intra-office guide, and I had no idea it lived on the internet anywhere... To answer your question, yes, I am that Ryan Stewart, and I'm glad you enjoyed the recipe. It was complex enough to scare some people off :)

Comment: Wait... Andrew Thompson from comp.lang.java.help/.programmer many moons ago?? I used to post there a lot. Not sure if I used my real name or went under the pseudonym zaphod or zzantozz... Small world, isn't it?

Comment: @Andrew: after using stackoverflow for a bit, I realized you probably didn't get notified of my previous comments because of the notification rules. Just drawing your attention back here in case you didn't see my reply.

Comment: @Ryan I didn't see it!  Though I'm having trouble figuring how the quotes/notification works.  Most of the times recently when I add an @name at the start of a comment it gets 'swallowed' by the site software.  Drop me a line to andrewthommo at gmail if you don't mind, I've lost your email address and would like to keep in touch.  And yes, I am *that* Andrew Thompson.  ;)